# Track Social Shares from Youtube Iframe Player with JavaScript

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, analytics, youtube-javascript-api

Youtube now has social sharing options in their embedded iframe player. Here is a screenshot: https://flic.kr/p/vneeF7

In the Youtube Developer API documentation, there is information about various events that your JavaScript can listen to such as video play/pause/skip/milestone etc. This is necessary for non-YouTube analytics software (such as Adobe Analytics) to track the interactions.

However the API docs as of July 21, 2015 say nothing about the social share feature or how to listen for events when it is used.

Can anyone describe how to track these events or point to documentation?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the only events the API can track are: `onReady`, `onStateChange`, `onPlaybackQualityChange`, `onPlaybackRateChange`, `onError`, and `onApiChange`, so I don't think what you're asking for is currently supported. Maybe you could use an onHover and onClick listener for the iframe and see if a new window was opened, then check what website that was for (e.g. Facebook, Pinterest, etc.). Alternatively, you could submit a feature request for it [here](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/list).